# Run javascript function from cmd

Tags: php, javascript, curl

Hi i was trying to emulate a post created from javascript in a site with curl from a php script but it seems some variables have the same name and they get overwritten, is there a way to run the script itself from command promt, assuming i make the necessary changes to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... you can always install [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) and then just write in terminal: `node <filename>`